# Why does this regex fail when trying to tell if there is a numeric character or more than one numeric character in the middle of a pattern?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string, regex-group

```py
import re

input_text = "hay alrededor de 4 coches el dia 7 del mes 5" #example 1
input_text = "Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 8 de este año 2023"  #example 2
input_text = "Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 7 de noviembre"  #example 3
input_text = "Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 1º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 7º dia del mes de noviembre"  #example 4


#for days
standard_number_of_digits_re_1 = r"(?:del dia|de el dia|el dia|del|de el|el)[\s|]*(\b\d{1}\b)"
standard_number_of_digits_re_2 = r"(\b\d{1}\b)[\s|]*º[\s|]*dia"

re_1_and_re_2 = r"(?:" + standard_number_of_digits_re_1 + r"|" + standard_number_of_digits_re_2  + r")"

#for months
#standard_number_of_digits_re_3 = re_1_and_re_2 + r"(?:del mes|de el mes|del|de el)[\s|]*(\b\d{1}\b)"
#standard_number_of_digits_re_4 = re_1_and_re_2 + r"(?:del mes|de el mes|del|de el)[\s|]*(\b\d{1}\b)[\s|]*(?:º[\s|]*mes del año|º[\s|]*mes)"

standard_number_of_digits_re_3 = r"(?:del mes|de el mes|del|de el)[\s|]*(\b\d)"
standard_number_of_digits_re_4 = r"(?:del mes|de el mes|del|de el)[\s|]*(\b\d)[\s|]*(?:º[\s|]*mes del año|º[\s|]*mes)"


#replacement with this conditions, and put '0' in front a day number only if it is one number and not two(or more numbers)
#  example: '1' --> '01'  or  '10' --> '10'
input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_3, r"0\1", input_text)
input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_4, r"0\1", input_text)
input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_1, r"0\1", input_text)
input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_2, r"0\1", input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) #output
```

The problem I'm having is that the regex don't seem to work correctly since I can't do the replacements, but trying in several code editors I notice these 2 things:

- In the Regex Debuger https://regex101.com/r/TfsKHZ/1 the regex appear to catch the correct text groups, but even so within the code they fail

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- In the SublimeText editor, when I put an `r` in front of `"(?:"` the whole line is immediately put as if it were a string of characters although you can see how this string is separated with operators in the middle in charge of the concatenation, however in StackOverflow that line is displayed correctly.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

I do not know if these observations are important in the malfunction of these regex, but for some reason that I cannot find, the regex cannot extract the text to be edited by placing (if applicable) a 0 in front.

Leaving the output should be like this when printing them:

```
"hay alrededor de 4 coches el dia 07 del mes 05" #for example 1
"Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 08 de este año 2023"  #for example 2
"Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 07 de noviembre"  #for example 3
"Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 01º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 07º dia del mes de noviembre"  #for example 4
```

What modifications should I make to get these results? I think the problem is in this part of the regex `(\b\d{1}\b)`

---

Edited code

```py
import re

input_text = "hay alrededor de 4 coches el dia 7 del mes 5" #example 1
#input_text = "Serian 4 unidades de mermelada para el dia 04 del 8 de este año 2023"  #example 2
input_text = "Hay 10 unidades para el dia 15 del 12 y seran 9 ya para el 7 de noviembre"  #example 3
#input_text = "Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 1º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 7º dia del mes de noviembre"  #example 4

#for days
standard_number_of_digits_re_1 = r"(?:del dia|de el dia|el dia|del|de el|el)[\s|]*(\b\d)"
standard_number_of_digits_re_2 = r"(\b\d)[\s|]*º[\s|]*dia"

#for months
standard_number_of_digits_re_3 = r"(?:del mes|de el mes|del|de el)[\s|]*(\b\d)"
standard_number_of_digits_re_4 = r"(?:del mes|de el mes|del|de el)[\s|]*(\b\d)[\s|]*(?:º[\s|]*mes del año|º[\s|]*mes)"


#replacement with this conditions, and put '0' in front a day number only if it is one number and not two(or more numbers)
#  example: '1' --> '01'  or  '10' --> '10'
input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_3, r"0\1", input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) #output

input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_4, r"0\1", input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) #output

input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_1, r"0\1", input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) #output

input_text = re.sub(standard_number_of_digits_re_2, r"0\1", input_text)

print(repr(input_text)) #output
```

The problem is for example in the example 3 :

```py
'Hay 10 unidades para 015 012 y seran 9 ya para 07 de noviembre'
```

And the correct output is:

```
'Hay 10 unidades para 15 12 y seran 9 ya para 07 de noviembre'
```

Comment: Why do you have `[\s|]*` instead of just `\s*`? There are no `|` characters in any of your examples.

Comment: In your regex tester you have PCRE flavor selected. When you change to Python it doesn't match.

Comment: Contrary to your desired output, your replacement string `r"0\1"` will result in everything that is matched being deleted from the input text except the captured single digit.

Comment: @Barmar I had not taken that into account, I thought that regular expressions did not change from one language to another, that's why I left the editor by default

Comment: Why would it have that menu if they didn't change?

Comment: @MatiasNicolasRodriguez Additional to Barmar's answer, have a look [at this sample](https://regex101.com/r/4fupIc/1) which I took out from your code and tried to improve. You can use `(?!\d)` as a right boundary - drop any left boundary between `(?:words)` and `\d`. Further as mentioned starting part containing the words needs to be captured and used in replacement or it's removed.

Comment: @bubble bubble Thanks, the problem that i have is in the example 4 `"Hay 10 unidades para el 15 del 1º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 7º dia del mes de noviembre"` where it erroneously transforms `15` into `015`

Comment: @matias, I tried your code, but got `"Hay 10 unidades para el 15 01º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para el 7º dia del mes de noviembre"` for example 4. Do you update the code?

Comment: @ILS I kept exactly the same code that is published in the question, the only change I made was as Barman said, change `(\b\d{1}\b)` to `(\b\d)`, but the only problem with this is that this regex adds a leading 0 even to numbers that already have 2 or more values, for example `15` to `015`, the value of `15` should not be normalized since it already counts 2 values

Comment: @matias, that's strange! I can not reproduce your problem. But I guess that `"15"` -> `"015"` is because `"el 1"` matches the pattern `standard_number_of_digits_re_1` and is changed to `"el 01"`. Check by printing after each substitution? BTW, `"(?:del dia|de el dia|el dia|del|de el|el)"` should be equivalent to `"(?:del dia|el dia|del|el)"`

Comment: @ILS There I have added the new edited code to the question, and you will see that the error of adding `"0"` in front of values with 2 numbers appears

Comment: Well, I reproduce that. As mentioned by @bobblebubble, adding negative lookahead `"(?!\d)"` at the end of `standard_number_of_digits_re_1` solves it.

Comment: You are right, I had misunderstood Bubblebubble, and by mistake put `"(?!\d)"` in the place of `"(\b\d)"` but not after it. Really thank you all for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of `\b` after `\d{1}`. Python considers `º` to be a word character, so there's no word boundary between `7` and `º`. You don't need to match a word boundary, since the regexp only allows spaces or `|` between the number and `º`.

There's also no need for `{1}`. All patterns match 1 time unless they're quantified, so `{1}` is redundant.

```
(\b\d)[\s|]*º[\s|]*dia
```

https://regex101.com/r/84QDbp/1

Comment: Thank you very much, I just tried the regex and the only problem it has is that when there are more than one numerical value, it places the `"0"` in front of the same, for example  in the example 1 mistakenly converts  `'15' ` to  `'015' ` and get this wrong output string  `'Hay 10 unidades para 015 01º mes del año y seran alrededor de 9 para 07º dia del mes de noviembre' `

Comment: That doesn't happen: https://regex101.com/r/84QDbp/2

Comment: Example 1 doesn't have `º` character so this regexp doesn't match it.

Comment: In example 1 the program uses `standard_number_of_digits_re_1 = r"(?:del dia|de el dia|el dia|del|de el|el)[\s|]*(\b\d)"`, but I have a problem with `15` in the example 4, because it's become in `015`

Comment: You were only supposed to remove the `\b` before `º`. The rest of the regexp should stay the same.

Comment: I have kept all the regex the same so just change `(\b\d{1}\b)` to `(\b\d)`, That's why in the original that I put together I had put `{1}` since I thought it would work to limit it to only being a single numeric character